# Automating Big Query table usage measurements

Tags: python, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

[In this illuminating answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288698/google-big-query-data-measurement) a technique is presented to get the data sizes from statically coded datasets that live in a Google Big Query Project.

To further automate this, I am operating in a Python Jupyter notebook environment using the BQ wrapper to make BQ Queries inside the Python.  I would like to construct a Big Query that will fetch all the datasets that live in my Project (they have the form of an 8- or 9-digit identifier) as a first step to feed into a Python data structure,  then use the referenced answer programmatically to get table sizes for all the identified datasets.  Is there a way to do this?